# transfer domain on bluehost to point to heroku app

Tags: heroku, deployment, bluehost

I have a domain registered on bluehost and Im trying to point the DNS to my heroku app. I have changed the www entry to the provided target. I also added the domain in heroku (once with the www and once without). The domain name is still responded to with the bluehost hosted app and not redirecting to the heroku instance. Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is any A record.